# How to update the Pivot tables in different sheets automatically when add new data to source/master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 master sheet (source table) and 3 different pivot table sheets and each sheet has 3 pivot tables.

If i add new data to my source table and run the macro, it should update all the pivot tables in all pivot sheets. i can't seems to find the exact code. i have done search but fail to find any source.

I know how to refresh it as if i change anything in the existing source file, and run the macro, it changes but new data do to update

any advice or simple code will help me solve this issue

thanks

I have used few refresh codes but they dont work on the adding the new data and pivot tables automatically update

Comment: If you use a named (dynamic) range for your source data then the updates should be automatic...

Comment: https://excelchamps.com/pivot-table/auto-update-range/

Answer (score 0):

To update the pivot table after the source data has changed, you need to refresh the pivot cache, not the pivot table. If your pivot table variable is named `pt` try `pt.PivotCache.Refresh`